# (Winsock) SMTP server not receiving anything

Tags: c++, networking, smtp, winsock2

I'm trying to create a simple SMTP server using Windows Winsock, and currently it's just a TCP server printing whatever it receives. However, when I connect to it, it's not receiving any data; it's getting connections but nothing else (not even disconnection messages). If I change the port to anything but 25, everything works. The port is open and allowed in the firewall. What could be the cause?

Edit: Found a solution, check out my own answer.

Comment: did you send the message you're supposed to send when the connection is opened? The client is probably waiting for it. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-3.1

Comment: Yes but nothing is being received on the client side either. However, is that really default for port 25? Shouldn't I still be able to create a TCP connection on port 25 without SMTP stuff?

Comment: oh, you aren't using an SMTP client to connect to it?

Comment: I have tried but no difference, still only get the connection but nothing is received.

Comment: @SamuelMattsson Then please [edit] your question to show your actual server code.  You are likely doing something wrong with it, but wee can't see what you are really doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it was Norton messing with me all along. If someone's having the same problem, I solved it by going into Norton -> Settings -> Antivirus and turning off Email Antivirus Scan.

Answer (score 0):

The [SMTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) requires the *server* to send a greeting to the client before the client can then send any commands:

> 3.1.  Session Initiation
>
> An SMTP session is initiated when a client opens a connection to a server **and the server responds with an opening message.**
>
> ...
>
> 3.2.  Client Initiation
>
> **Once the server has sent the greeting (welcoming) message and the client has received it**, the client normally sends the EHLO command to the server, indicating the client's identity...
>
> ...
>
> 4.3.1.  Sequencing Overview
>
> The communication between the sender and receiver is an alternating dialogue, controlled by the sender.  As such, the sender issues a command and the receiver responds with a reply.  Unless other arrangements are negotiated through service extensions, the sender MUST wait for this response before sending further commands.  **One important reply is the connection greeting.  Normally, a receiver will send a 220 "Service ready" reply when the connection is completed.  The sender SHOULD wait for this greeting message before sending any commands.** ...

Comment: But as far as I understand, port 25 isn't "bound" to the SMTP protocol, just reserved for it (just like port 80 isn't "bound" to HTTP), so shouldn't I technically be able to communicate regularly through a TCP connection on port 25?

Comment: @SamuelMattsson depends on the system.  For instance, on most systems, ports < 1024 are reserved and can't even be open by non-admin processes.  But if you can open such a port, and make a connection to it, then yes, communication is possible, whether it is a SMTP or something else.  Of course, the client and server have to agree on which protocol to actually use in order to have *meaningful* communication with each other.